# Delete an item from oneToMany relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following Gallery entity

```
class Gallery
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tessa\GalleryBundle\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="gallery", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $photos;

    /* ... */
}
```

This `gallery` is linked with a `manyToOne` relationship to a `PointOfInterest` entity. Here is the declaration

```
class PointOfInterest
{
 /* ... */
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tessa\GalleryBundle\Entity\Gallery", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $gallery;
 /* ... */
```

I also use a Form to update the `PointOfInterest` entity. Here is the form declaration

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('name',           'text')
            ->add('gallery',        new GalleryType())
       ;
}
```

and the `GalleryType` declaration.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('photos', 'collection', array('type'          => new PhotoType(),
                                            'required'      => false,
                                            'allow_add'     => true,
                                            'allow_delete'  => true,
                                            'by_reference'  => false
                                            ))
    ;
}
```

When I edit the `PoI` I can add photos to the gallery without problem, but I can't delete anything.

I tried to hook on gallery `PreUpdate`, but it is never called. I printed output in `removePhotos` method of `Gallery` entity, and the photos are removed from the gallery. I then suspect the Gallery to never be persisted.

Here is the code when I persist the `PoI` after editing.

```
private function handleForm($elem, $is_new)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new CircuitType, $elem);

    $request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($elem);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('tessa_circuit_index'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('TessaUserBundle:Circuits:add.'.'html'.'.twig',
        array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'is_new' => $is_new,
        ));
}
```

Comment: What is the displayed error ?

Comment: There's no error. I just don't know how to edit my code to make this behave like I want.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923919/symfony2-form-collection-how-to-remove-entity-from-a-collection

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There is [article in Symfony2 cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-tags-to-be-removed) about handling this type of situation. As you have OneToMany relationship, you have to remove related objects manually in controller.

**Edit**:
Or you can make use of [Doctrine's orphan removal](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal) feature.

```
class Gallery
{
    //...    

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photo", mappedBy="gallery", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $photos;

    //...

    public function removePhotos($photo)
    {
        $this->photos->remove($photo);
        $photo->setGallery(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that Gallery not then be able to work by itself. I use it in serveral entities, and would need to duplicate my code over. I would like to find a DRY solution.

Comment: @TomAhh In this case I dont see any standard solution, except maybe you can try set `orphanRemoval=true` on `$photos` association. And then call `$photo->setGallery(null)` inside `removePhotos($photo)` method of gallery.

Comment: That's a perfect solution, thanks ! It now works exactly like I want it too. Could you update your answer so that I can validate it ?

Comment: +1 for the Edit about Doctrine's orphan removal feature - this is what made things work for me.

Comment: On Doctrine v2.5 `->remove($photo)` throws error, instead `removeElement()` worked