# Delete child only doctrine2 symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to delete Child, but it also deletes its parent and all other children
Here's my parent entity : annonce

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Candidature", mappedBy="annonce",orphanRemoval=true )
     */
    private $candidatures;
```

and here's my child entity: candidature

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Annonce", inversedBy="candidatures" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_annonce", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
     */
    private $annonce;
```

here's my delete action on parent:

```
public function supprimerAction($id)
    {

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $annonce=$em->getRepository(Annonce::class)->find($id);
        $em->remove($annonce);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute("mesAnnonces");
    }
```

and here's my delete action on child candidature

```
 public function supprimerAction($id)
    {

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $candidature=$em->getRepository(Candidature::class)->find($id);
        $em->remove($candidature);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute("mesCandidatures");
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete an item from oneToMany relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197483/delete-an-item-from-onetomany-relationship)

Comment: Weird. Sorry to ask you that but did you double check that you are calling just the `supprimerAction` in your CandidatureController?

Comment: No i have all crud actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `orphanRemoval`, you should use `onDelete=CASCADE`.

As `Candidature::annonce` can't be false, you will never have any orphans, it's not possible.
All you need is to delete every `Candidature` entry from the DB when you delete the related `Annonce` entry.
And deleting a single `Candidature` won't affect the parent `Annonce` this way.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Candidature", mappedBy="annonce" )
 */
private $candidatures;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Annonce", inversedBy="candidatures" )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
 */
private $annonce;
```

> 

On a side note, I would suggest to make proper `supprimerAction()`.
At least something like this:

```
public function supprimerAction(Annonce $annonce) {
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove($annonce);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute("mesAnnonces");
}

public function supprimerAction(Candidature $candidature) {
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove($candidature);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute("mesCandidatures");
}
```

Though, even this isn't proper enough.
There is no form in this, no CSRF token either.
This would be more secure :

```
public function supprimerAction(Request $request, Annonce $annonce) {
    $form=$this->createFormBuilder()
         ->setAction($this->generateUrl('annonce_supprimer', array('id'=>$annonce->getId())))
         ->setMethod('DELETE')
         ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($annonce);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute("mesAnnonces");
    }

    return $this->render('annonce_supprimer.html.twig', array(
        'annonce'=>$annonce,
        'form'=>$form,
    ));
}

public function supprimerAction(Request $request, Candidature $candidature) {
    $form=$this->createFormBuilder()
               ->setAction($this->generateUrl('annonce_supprimer', array('id'=>$candidature->getId())))
               ->setMethod('DELETE')
               ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($candidature);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute("mesCandidatures");
    }

    return $this->render('candidature_supprimer.html.twig', array(
        'candidature'=>$candidature,
        'form'=>$form,
    ));
}
```

Comment: still didn't work, it deleted all children and the parent once i tried to delete only one child

Comment: Shouldn't be the case. Have you updated database after making this change? `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`.

Comment: @AchrefBannouri Also, is there ither relations in your two entities?

Comment: Then if it still doesn't works, you have another problem @AchrefBannouri You should complete your question and add all the relations in your two entities. The problem might be in them